# Raise LinkedIn Permissions from lite to basic

Tags: linkedin-api

I set up a new app for "Signin with LinkedIn" but only got the following scopes[image]

I tried to modify the scope to get `r_basicprofile` but could not find any way to do so. Even when I recreate one, it just does not allow me to choose the scopes.

When I try to force the scopes from the client, I get "unauthorized_scope_error".

How should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're looking to leverage the marketing APIs. See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/getting-access?view=li-lms-2022-12) on getting access to these.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, I filled in a form to get access to thos permissions. Will update when received

Comment: I had an "Access Denied" for "Marketing Developer Platform"

But I have no reason whatsoever.

I really need to have access to the user's information and i'm 100% sure that users are willing to give me this information.

How should I do ?

Comment: I would suggest reaching out to LinkedIn directly.

Comment: Thanks but I did already :-(